# String from byte array

Tags: java, string, arrays

I've got the following code:

```
byte[] byteArray=new byte[]{-104, 5, -53, -50, -22};
String s=new String(byteArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes()));
```

Result is `[63, 5, -53, -50, -22]`. Can anybody explain why? Why -104 became 63? Do I have to change encoding?

Comment: A nice example that a byte array does not fit for a `String`, which uses Unicode internally, namely an array of two-byte `char`. It always converts from and to `byte[]` using some encoding, the optional parameter you did not provide in `new String` and `getBytes`.

Comment: What do the bytes mean? Do they represent text (in whatever character encoding), or are they just random bytes from somewhere? `String` is not a suitable container for arbitrary bytes, so don't try to use it for that purpose.

Comment: @Jesper, but what is suitable?

Comment: @Tony a `String` is only for storing text. Only if you have bytes that you know represent text encoded in whatever character encoding (UTF-8, ASCII, ...), it makes sense to convert the bytes to characters in a `String`.